# What is the convention around derivative information?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am working on a service that provides information about a few related entities, somewhat like a database. Suppose that there's calls to retrieve information about a school:

```
service MySchool {
    rpc GetClassRoom (ClassRoomRequest) returns (ClassRoom);
    rpc GetStudent (StudentRequest) returns (Student);
}
```

Now, suppose that I want to find out a class room's information, I'd receive a proto that looks like so:

```
message ClassRoom {
    string id = 1;
    string address = 2;
    string teacher = 3;
}
```

Sometimes I also want to know all of the students of the classroom. I am struggling to think which is the better design pattern.

Option A) Add an extra rpc like so: `rpc GetClassRoomStudents (ClassRoomRequest) returns (ClassRoomStudents)`, where `ClassRoomStudents` has a single field `repeated Student students`. This technique requires more than one call to get all the information that we want (and many if we wanted to know information for more than one classroom).

Option B) Add an extra `repeated Student students` field to the `ClassRoom` proto, and B') Fill it up only when necessary, or B") Fill it up whenever the server receives a `GetClassRoom` call. This may sometimes fetch extra information, or lead to ambiguity according to what fields are filled up.

I am not sure what's the best / most conventional way of dealing with this. How have some of you dealt with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer. It's a tradeoff between simplicity (option A) and performance (option B), and it depends on the situation which solution is best.

In general, I'd recommend to go with the simple solution first, unless your measurements demonstrate that it leads to performance issues. At that point, it's easy to add `repeated Student students` to `ClassRoom` and a field `bool fetch_students [default=false]` to `ClassRoomRequest`. Then clients are free to continue using the simple API, or choose to upgrade to the more performant API if they need to.

Note that this isn't specific to gRPC; the same issue is seen in REST APIs, and basically almost any request/response model.